# return single object based on ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

hi im currently building something for fun that allows users to post anything. and im experincing some problems here is my code.

```js
 return details.findOne({'data': {$elemMatch: {'_id':req.params.id}}}).then((a) => {
            return res.render('post', { a });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

i only want this to return one post i thought by using the objectId id would be able todo that but it seems to return everything in the data array anybody have any ideas below is my schema.

i need this to only return the single object whos objId is in the url

```js
    var schemaMode = new mongoose.Schema({
        email: {type: String, required: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true},
        username: {type: String,required:true},
        data: [{
            author: String,
            title: String,
            comments: [String],
            article: String,
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Try `return details.find().select({'data': {$elemMatch: {'_id':req.params.id}}}).then((a) => {
            return res.render('post', { a });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));`

Answer (score 0):

```
Details.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundObject){
   //foundObject contains the object with the ._id matching req.params.id
});
```

if you only want certain fields back, like you want the object to only have its data field for example, then you do:

```
Details.findById(req.params.id, "data",
function(err, foundObject){
   //foundObject contains the object with the ._id matching req.params.id
});
```

OR

```
Details.findById(req.params.id).select("data")
.exec(function(err, foundObject){
   //foundObject contains the object with the ._id matching req.params.id
});
```

to be clear, in the code above, Details is the imported (with require) schema (in your case, the one named schemaMode)

Comment: i only want the data in the data array will this work for that or only the email password etc fields?

Comment: @seancarroll yes it will work, i edited the answer so the example is with the data field

Comment: doesnt seem to be working i console.log foundObject and its returning null ?

Comment: @seancarroll are you using the proper schema name ? in my example i used Details with a capital. in your code you were using "details", lowercase d, keep the name of the schema as it is in your own code. but if it is already correct, then getting null means the req.params.id didn't match any object's _id from the collection

Comment: ye i used proper schema name lowercase d i solved it tho thanks for the help :)

Comment: what was the problem causing it to return null ?

Comment: i still dont know somebody commented this tho return details.find().select({'data': {$elemMatch: {'_id':req.params.id}}}).then((a) => { return res.render('post', { a }); }).catch(err => console.log(err)); and it worked still tryna find out why it was returning null

Answer (score 0):

Is "data" your "post"? If so, I think you need a projection.

```
    return details.findOne({'data': {$elemMatch: {'_id':req.params.id}}},{'data.$'}).then((a) => {
        return res.render('post', { a.data[0] });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

'data.$' will project you the whole model, filled only with the desired "data"/"post"